# .Net core 2.2 webap not resolving net standard 2 class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2

I have webapp (.netcore2.2) and I have a service interface and class sitting in the main application folder and models sitting in a separate but shared .netstandard2 class library. I don't seem to be able to reference the models in my service classes/interfaces. The using statement doesn't detect the namespace of my models Shared.Models from services folder in the main application - namespace WebApp.Services.

I tried just a standard .netframework console app with a class library and all worked fine - just to prove it wasn't something screwy with the VS studio install (VS2019). So it would appear to be an just related to the .netcore2 application. Tried over and over again - doing my head in :-(

Comment: Could please provide some code snippet for this? Have you tried adding the reference to your services?

Comment: Post the contents from the xsproj file, to prove yopu added a reference.

Comment: Thanks @HenkHolterman I hadn't manually added   `<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\Shared.csproj" />  
  </ItemGroup>`   to the csproj file. Is this different to classic dotnet? With a stock standard dotNet solution my Resharper and intellisense detects the shared project and asks me if I'd like to import the shared project. With the dotnet core neither intellisense nor Resharper detected anything until I manually added the above reference even though both projects were under the same solution file. I'm guessing this is unique to dotnet core?

Comment: You always have to have the reference. You can right-click on the Dependencies and add it. Your tooling-support may vary, I don't know.